# Where can i found default android xml drawables?

Tags: android, android-drawable

I would like to use the default ice cream sandwich radio button but not with ligth blue color. I would like to recolor it.

Can i somewhere found the original .xml files to recolor and use it in my project?

Comment: In your SDK folder, API-Level, under `data/res/drawable`

Comment: adt-bundl\sdk\platforms\android-level\data\res\drawable

Comment: @FrankN.Stein Add as an answer so i could accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in your SDK folder, API-Level, under `data/res/drawable`

Answer (score 1):

Take a look in the Android sources:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res

Most of the drawables use styles, so you can just change the colors by setting styles in your app.

Like here:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values/styles.xml